# Kronecher product of a deterministic vector with a random vector

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume vector $a=[1,1,1,1,1]^T$ and vector $b_{5 \times 1}$ whose elements can be $0$ or $1$ with the probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

1) Is $a \otimes b$ a fully random vector?

2) The same question when we fix some elements of $b$ equal to $1$.

Comment: What is a "fully random" vector?

Comment: By fully random here, I mean all the elements can be 0 or 1 by the probability 1/2